# reading a POST request XML in jsp

Tags: xml, jsp, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I'm trying to send a XML to a jsp using XMLHttpRequest. Can anybody tell me how to read the request XML in jsp? Below is the code i'm using to do a POST call.

Thanks in advance!

```
var xmlHttpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttpRequest.open("POST",url,true);
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
xmlHttpRequest.send("<xml><user_id>F1528</user_id></xml>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but it seems like [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) should provide an easy solution:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<x:parse doc="${pageContext.request.reader}" var="parsedXml"/>
```

Which should result in a page-scoped var called `parsedXml`.

Comment: kschneid - is there a way to do this in a scriptlet?

Comment: Of course you can do it in a scriptlet, it's just more work. Calling `request.getReader` will get you a `BufferedReader` that you can then use to do standard XML parsing.

Answer (score 1):

`JSP's` should be used to generate pages and `Servlets` should be used to process the business logic.

I would suggest you to read the request body in Servlet. Set the read body to the request attribute and forward the request to JSP which renders the request body.

Comment: ramesh - you are correct. just for now, i want to know how its done in jsp. if i do a http GET, i read the parameters in the jsp using request.getParameters. how can i parse an XML sent using http POST?

Comment: In that case, you can use the tag provided by JSTL.<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<x:parse doc="${pageContext.request.reader}" var="parsedXml"/>

Comment: I have to write the POST data to a file. Thats why for the time being im trying to do this in jsp. can this be done in a scriptlet?